# WP Plugin "upgrader_process_complete" is not working for auto update

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

In my plugin, I am trying to do some action after plugin update. I use `upgrader_process_complete` hook. It's working fine if I update plugin manually. But, when plugin automatically update it's does not work.

My code :

```
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', array($this, 'after_upgrade_callback'),10, 2); 

// After Update Plugin Callback
function after_upgrade_callback( $upgrader_object, $options ) {

  $current_plugin_path_name = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

  if ($options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' ) {
    foreach($options['plugins'] as $each_plugin) {
      if ($each_plugin==$current_plugin_path_name) {
        // do something 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it correct for auto update or any other way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow, I want this ans also.

Comment: @Mhrishad Please see the ans :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue and solution -

When I update manually the `$options['plugins']` looks like this.

And when update automatically the $options['plugin'] looks like this.

The different in `option` index (`option` and `options`).

So I add `isset` condition and solve my problem.

**Updated**

```
  // After Update Plugin Callback
  function after_upgrade_callback( $upgrader_object, $options ) {

    $current_plugin_path_name = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

    if ( isset( $options['plugins'] ) && is_array( $options['plugins'] ) ) {
      foreach($options['plugins'] as $each_plugin) {
        if ($each_plugin == $current_plugin_path_name) {
          // action

        }
      }
    }elseif(isset( $options['plugins'] ) && ($options['plugins'] != "")){
      if ($options['plugins'] == $current_plugin_path_name) {
        // action

      }
    }elseif(isset( $options['plugin'] ) && ($options['plugin'] != "")){
      if ($options['plugin'] == $current_plugin_path_name) {
        // action

      }
    }
  }
```